# Get index of element in list that has specific substring

Tags: python, list, substring

So I am building a stock finder project thing and I am looking to find stock tickers for stock names that contain a sub-string of the full name.

For example passing Apple as stockName would return AAPL because Apple is a substring of Apple, Inc. Same for Microsoft or Micros returning MSFT because Microsoft or Micros being a substring of Microsoft Corporation.

This is my existing code that returns errors if I put in a substring:

```
def getStockTicker(stockName):
    return companyTickers[companyNames.index(stockName)]
```

Does anyone has any ideas?

EDIT: I have handled the error so that if nothing is found in companyNames it returns a ValueError

Comment: what error did it show give sample input output

Comment: did you try printing `companyNames.index(stockName)`

Comment: you should use `.find` instead of `.index`: **.find** will return -1 if substring not found otherwise return its index. **.index** on the other hand will throw *ValueError* if substring not found

Comment: Perhaps, you could build a regex to see if any of those letters are in it.

Does the string 'A' also result in 'AAPL'?

Comment: @Anzel what data type are you refering to? `list` does not have `find` method and `index` method is not searching for substrings but for list elements.

Comment: @beezz when talking about **substring** I'm expecting strings isn't it? `.index` can be used to verify if a substring is in the string

Comment: @Anzel I'm asking what **container** type has method `find` and `index` that works the way you are describing.

Comment: but I do agree the whole question isn't clear enough... neither does OP provide what the **companyTickers** is or other related code, thus I do not provide any answer but just leaving comments here :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think that two separate lists, one of company names and one of company ticker Ids, is not the right data structure.

Are you familiar with the Python `dict`? It maps keys to values. If you use the company name as the key and the ticker symbol as the value, declaring a `dict` would look like this:

```
companies = {
    'Apple, Inc.': 'AAPL',
    'Microsoft Corporation': 'MSFT'
}
```

And retrieving a given ticker symbol using the whole name looks like:

```
companies['Apple, Inc.']  # returns 'AAPL'
```

As for retrieving tickers based on a substring, it's perfectly doable. One thing to be wary of: the same substring might match multiple keys so you want to return a list of possible matches instead of the first possible match.

```
companies = {...}

def get_ticker_symbol(company):
    return [value for key, value in companies.items() if company in key]
```

Comment: Great idea. I completely forgot about dictionaries - been out of Python for too long. I'll see if it'll work. Thanks!

Comment: I agree this approach, **sidenote**: I suggest using a proper database (indexing and LIKE search) for this sort of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

`stockName in someFullString` will tell you if `stockName` is a substring of `someFullString`.

Given that, you can create a generator containing only string whose `stockName` is a substring of and retrieve the index of the first one, if any:

```
def getStockTicker(stockName):
    for fullString in (s for s in companyNames if stockName in s):
        return companyTickers[companyNames.index(fullString)]
    # at this point, stockName is not a substring of anything in compagnyNames
    return None # or raise an exception, or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no other way than to iterate over the `companyNames` and check if it contains `stockName`.

```
def getStockTicker(stockName):
    for index, companyName in enumerate(companyNames):
        if stockName in companyName: 
            return companyTickers[index]
```